# Top handle, metal fireplace screen warms. Unit not lit, and days after use. No pilot light on unit, has internal fan

Tags: gas, fireplace, propane

Top handle, metal fireplace screen warms. Unit not lit, and days after use. Unit is enclosed propane burner, with mantel. There's an internal fan and no pilot light on unit, but has thermocouple. Phenomenon happens randomly especially daytime, while it tends to stop at night. All this, without the unit being lit at all. Support personnel say they are baffled and the unit is new. Thermocouple was adjusted last week to supply adequate flame height.

Comment: Sun light? The sun can heat/warm up stuff it shines on. The warmth can last a few hours if hot enough or has enough mass.

Comment: Is this handle in the flow of air coming out of the unit?  If so, is it warm/hot outside when you experience this?  If so, could it be possible that something is causing a back draft down your chimney and hot outside air is getting pulled inside, heating the handle?  And how warm is warm?  Body temperature (i.e. slightly above ambient), hot water temperature, or "give you burns when touching" temperature?

Comment: We really need a picture or two and some additional information to answer this...

Comment: To answer crip659 and Milwrdfan (& thanks to both): no direct sun. Unit is in a darkish living room. To 2nd question: 'Warm' is 'warmer than room temp. so noticeable when touched, moderately. The unit isn't lit, so it doesn't generate heat via itself or the inside fan. the screen assembly doesn't pick up the heat of the fireplace -- it's completely insulated from that. The room temperature over 24 hrs doesn't vary radically, only by a few degrees. The air outside is cool, not hot. That's why this is a reaaal mystery.

Comment: Since there's no pilot, they must use electricity. It probably has the electronics up there, and the little circuit doesn't have the most efficient AC-DC (low voltage) conversion, thus shedding a watt or two all the time and warming the surrounding exterior.

Comment: Thanks Dan for that. I'll pass it to my friend, a retired electrician who did some of the wiring. The only flaw I can think of (to the theory) is the fact that the unusual heating in the handle is random and depends on how cool air currents are going through the room (which may only vary by 10  degrees from morning to evening); In that case, maybe it's a sensor problem. On the other hand, nothing is supposed to heat only the handle on the front screen in the first place.

Comment: You could test my theory by turning of power to the fireplace at the breaker and see if that affects the temp an hour or two later.